# Page.PreLoad Event not showing up in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am wondering why I can't see all page events in visual studio 2008, when I click on the events combobox, only the page_load event is in there. What can I do to see all page life cycle events in the combo, so I can just click it to generate the event template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is page life cycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

you can't see events because they are not written in code page yet, you have to write them yourself (if you mean the combo box in code behind page on top)

if you already have AutoEventWireup="true" set, just write in code:

```
protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // handle code
}
```